# Getting an [null] response from SQL query using json_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, coalesce, aggregate-filter

Still learning SQL/PostgreSQL. I am struggling to figure out how to stop returning an array with a null value as `[null]` and instead just return an empty array.

```
COALESCE(
  json_agg(
    CASE 
      WHEN socials.id IS NULL THEN NULL 
      ELSE json_build_object('id', socials.id, 'name', socials.social_id, 'url', socials.url)
    END
  ), '[]'
) AS socials
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? From what I understood, `COALESCE` is used to basically replace when the return value is `null`/`false`. Am I wrong in thinking this way? Also what might be the issue with my SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer `COALESCE` does not do what you want since `json_agg()` never returns `null`, unless no input row qualifies. And `COALESCE` only kicks in for `null` input - not *`null`/`false`* like you put it!  (An array containing a single `null` value as array element is not the same as `null`!)

Use an aggregate `FILTER` clause instead:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(json_build_object('id', socials.id, 'name', socials.social_id, 'url', socials.url))
                FILTER (WHERE socials.id IS NOT NULL)
              , '[]') AS socials
```

*Now*, `COALESCE` can make sense, since you can get result rows, but the added `FILTER` clause can make the result of `json_agg()` `null`.

Depending on your undisclosed query, you might instead add an outer `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id', socials.id, 'name', socials.social_id, 'url', socials.url)) AS socials
FROM   ...
WHERE  socials.id IS NOT NULL
```

In this case, there is no point in adding an outer `COALESCE`, since you would get *no row* if the added `WHERE` clause filters all input rows.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation on what was missing and why it wasn't working. It was a good lesson for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a `FILTER` clause:

```
json_agg(...) FILTER (WHERE socials.id IS NOT NULL)
```